# how to redirect in joomla

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I'm trying to redirect this URL:

"http://pishgamanhesab.com/articles/accounting-papers/289-tax-returns.html" to this "http://pishgamanhesab.com/blog/%d8%b5%d9%81%d8%b1-%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%b5%d8%af-%d8%a7%d8%b8%d9%87%d8%a7%d8%b1%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85%d9%87-%d9%85%d8%a7%d9%84%db%8c%d8%a7%d8%aa%db%8c/"

with htaccess.txt, but don't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articles/accounting-papers/289-tax-returns.html(.*)$ /blog/%d8%b5%d9%81%d8%b1-%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%b5%d8%af-%d8%a7%d8%b8%d9%87%d8%a7%d8%b1%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85%d9%87-%d9%85%d8%a7%d9%84%db%8c%d8%a7%d8%aa%db%8c/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: You aren't getting any support here.  Try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Components->Redirects-> Click New

Fill the following field

Expired URL - http://pishgamanhesab.com/articles/accounting-papers/289-tax-returns.html

New URL - http://pishgamanhesab.com/blog/%d8%b5%d9%81%d8%b1-%d8%aa%d8%a7-%d8%b5%d8%af-%d8%a7%d8%b8%d9%87%d8%a7%d8%b1%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85%d9%87-%d9%85%d8%a7%d9%84%db%8c%d8%a7%d8%aa%db%8c/

Then save. It will automatically redirect. Its Joomla default component.